# Off-topic site picker has HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, close-dialog

For example, with Unix & Linux:

[image: Selecting a site]

[image: Selected, HTML entity is shown]

Comment: Those pesky HTMLs. Why can&apos;t they just play nice?

Comment: Why do you have 40 reputation?

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Bounties.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi because the cool kids don't need reputation to be awesome.

Comment: I _know_ this is a dupe.

Comment: @minitechη misunderstood the bug, *on select* you see it, gotcha

Comment: [FixItFixItFixIt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6PZhONZ3Ac) :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 Obligatory improvement: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=katzz57tmm4

Comment: @AnnaLear I debated linking that one but I decided to stick with the classic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed and deployed on meta, rolling out soon.